# Is there a LIKE operator in odata filter?

Tags: rest, odata

I'm trying to filter my data through OData where the field **FileRef** contains lets say `"/The root path/folder/subfolder"`, I tried with `substringof` like so:

`$filter=substringof("sites/my folder/subfolder", FileRef)`

But it seems doesn´t work, so I wonder if is there an operator **like** or something that i can use for achieve this.

Comment: Look a tutorial Odata: http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc444868693

Answer (score 54):

Consider contains: `$filter=contains(CompanyName,'Alfreds')`

Comment: I think contains is supported only from Odata 3 or 4. It's not available in version 2, AFAIK.

Comment: Also note that for contains() the arguments are reversed, as opposed to substringof(): contains(CompanyName,'Alfreds') vs substringof('Alfreds', CompanyName).

Answer (score 23):

```
$filter=substringof('Alfreds', CompanyName)
```

for more details see:
http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/url-conventions/ -->
5.1.2.4. Canonical Functions

Answer (score 10):

For me worked `$filter=indexof(CompanyName, 'Alfreds') gt -1`. This is case sensitive.

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
$filter=indexof(CompanyName, 'Alfreds') gt -1
```

This includes first index and above.

Answer (score 4):

For oData v2, you can try:

```
$filter=substringof('sites/my folder/subfolder', FileRef) eq true
```

Samples using public oData Service:

```
https://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers?$filter=substringof('Futterkiste',CompanyName) eq true

https://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers?$filter=substringof('London',City) eq true

https://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers?$filter=substringof('w',ContactName) eq true and substringof('London',City) eq true
```

Ref: [enter link description here](https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/)